# How to use limit and group by together in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, limit

With these sample tables

```
table_a               table_b
 column_1               column_1 column_2
  1                         1       A
  2                         1       B
  3                         2       C
  4                         3       D
  5                         4       E
```

the query below

```
SELECT table_a.column1,table_b.column2 
FROM table_a 
INNER JOIN table_b ON table_a.column1 = table_b.column_1
GROUP BY table_a.column1 LIMIT 3
```

gives only 2 results (limit is 3) since the value 1 is duplicating in table_b. How can i get 3 results with unique table_a.column1 values. In general how can i use group by and limit together with group by having no impact on the limit

Comment: Your question lacks clarity on what you would like to achive. The query in the question will run only if mysql is not configured to be in strict sql mode. I fail to see the reason for such query.

Comment: Sorry the question was wrong in my case there were only two values

Answer (score 0):

After minor adjustments with columns names (changing `column1` into `column_1` and `column2` into `column_2`) your query gives me exactly 3 rows of results.

```
1 A
2 C
3 D
```

Comment: Sorry the question was wrong in my case there were only two values